# Sard's theorem for absolutely continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Can anyone help me proving Sard's theorem where $ f $ is a real valued absolutely continuous function on $ [a,b] $ that is to prove $ f(A) $ is measure zero where $$ A = \{x\in [a,b]\ |\ f'(x) = 0 \}$$  I need to use the definition of absolute continuity of real functions using estimates on sum and possibly properties like $f$ being differentiable a.e , $ f' \in L^1 $ and validity of fundamental theorem of calculus. I can't figure out ways to replicate or generalize the proof for continuously differentiable functions.

Comment: Do you know [Vitali's covering lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma#Vitali.27s_covering_theorem_for_the_Lebesgue_measure)? That allows you to almost cover $A$ by a finite collection of disjoint open intervals (the difference is a set of arbitrarily small measure).

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! I got it...

Comment: Great! I highly encourage you to write up your solution and post it below. So other visitors can benefit too!

Answer (score 4):

Well its kind of weird to answer my own question but this is due to the visitors as pointed out by Willie Wong.  We can see here that for $ x\in A$ there exists $h_x$ such that $ |f(y)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon |y-x| $ for all $y \in [x,x+h_x] $. We can show all such $ [x,x+h_x] $ form a Vitali covering of $A$. So we have finitely many disjoint intervals $ I_1,...,I_k $ whose combined measure has very small difference with $A$ . So I estimate $$\lambda (f(A)) \leq \lambda(f(\cup_k I_k)) + \lambda (f(A\setminus \cup_k I_k )) $$ We can estimate both seperately where first one is obvious and second one by containing the set in a open set with small measure and using fundamental theorem of calculus and uniform integrability as for AC functions $f'\in L^1 $.

Comment: I currently don't see why the first estimate is obious. How can we estimate $\lambda(f(\bigcup_k I_k))$ easily? The idea is to use $|f(y) -f(x)| < \varepsilon |y-x|$, but there might be arbitrarily many intervals ($k$ might be arbitrarily large).

Comment: Actually, this is indeed quite easy, as the $I_k$ are disjoint and a subset of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Nevertheless, **you don't need absolute continuity** for this proof to work. You just have to use a slightly different version of Vitali's covering lemma (see Exercise 13 of Section 6.2 in Royden's "Real Analysis" 4th ed.). This has been shown in the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/113991/counterexample-to-sard-theorem-for-a-not-c1-map/114000#114000).

Comment: Here is my explanation of the multidimensional version. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nk9WyqWtcSo