Let $f\colon (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be nondecreasing and continuous. If $E=\{x\in (a,b)\mid f'(x)\text{ exists and } f'(x)=0\}$, then $\lambda(f(E))=0$
I need help to understand the proof below of the following theorem.

Let $f\colon (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary function. If $E=\{x\in (a,b)\mid f'(x)\text{ exists and }
f'(x)=0\}$, then $$\lambda(f(E))=0.$$
$\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

You pointed out this wonderful answer to me:

More precisely, let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be an arbitrary function, $\Sigma$ is the set of $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f'(x)$ exists and equals 0. Then $f(\Sigma)$ has measure 0.
By countable subadditivity of measure, we may assume that the domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$ rather than $\mathbb R$. Fix an $\varepsilon>0$. For every $x\in\Sigma$ there exists a subinterval $I_x\ni x$ of $[0,1]$ such that $f(5I_x)$ is contained in an interval $J_x$ with $m(J_x)<\varepsilon m(I_x)$. Here $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and $5I_x$ the interval 5 times longer than $I_x$ with the same midpoint. Now by Vitali's Covering Lemma there exists a countable collection $\{x_i\}$ such that the intervals $I_{x_i}$ are disjoint and the intervals $5I_{x_i}$ cover $\Sigma$. Since $I_{x_i}$ are disjoint, we have $\sum m(I_{x_i})\le 1$. Therefore $f(\Sigma)$ is covered by intervals $J_{x_i}$ whose total measure is no greater than $\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $f(\Sigma)$ has measure $0$.

This answer is certainly correct, but for me, who am just a student, it is too lacking in details that I cannot write. I can't translate what is said into symbols. Could someone be kind enough to explain the details of this answer to me?
Prior state of this question.
I was looking for some text or some suggestions to prove this statement using Vitali's lemma, but at first, under the additional
nondecreasingness and continuity assumptions for $f$, hoping the proof should prove to be more simplified.
I even decided to open a bounty, in the hope that someone will be able to provide me with a proof of this fact with these hypotheses using Vitali's Lemma. But since I didn't receive any answer, I shifted my attention to the more general result.

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/363208/42969

This is true without the nondecreasingness or the continuity assumption, see the answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/113991/counterexample-to-sards-theorem-for-a-non-c1-map/114000#114000

Thanks, but on the basis of these hypotheses the result should be simplified, right? Here I am looking for this simplified version.

The application of Vitali’s Lemma in the link I posted is really as simple as applications of Vitali’s Lemma go. So are you looking for a proof that does not use this lemma?

Here is another approach to the problem that does not require monotonicity.

@MittensThanks! But I would like to know if this fact can be proved with the Vitali covering theorem.

@JonathanHoleThanks!Since we have more hypotheses here, I believe that we can still do it with the vitali covering lemma, but by exploiting these hypotheses some simplifications will emerge somewhere compared to the general case. Here I am looking for a proof of this fact under these hypotheses that uses the Vitali covering lemma.

The inverse $g=f^{-1}$ is non-increasing, (hence of bounded variation,) so has a finite derivative almost everywhere, this gives the desired result.

@Steen82Thanks. But as I mentioned in the post I would like to solve the problem using Vitali's Covering Theorem.

Just saying, because you have more assumptions does not necessarily mean a simpler proof must exist. Please explai what exactly you do not like about the linked answers?

@NatMath The answer provided in the MO link given by Jonathan Hole proceeded by finding a collection of subintervals in an obvious way, then applying the Vitali covering lemma. It cannot reasonably get any simpler than that.

@Divide1918Thanks for your interest, the problem with that answer is that I can't understand it in detail. Could you rewrite it in an explicit and understandable way? the answer will still be accepted. Thank you.

Your tecent edit makes your post unclear: as Jonathan commented on June 13th while providing this MO link,  the proof in it holds without your nondecreasingness and continuity assumptions, but you insisted that you were looking for a simpler proof making use of these assumptions. Now you seem to have changed your mind and only want to understand that proof, without your additional hypothesis. If so, you should: 1) remove them explicitely from your question; 2)  explain what exactly you do not understand in that proof.

@AnneBauvalI didn't change because I wanted to share with everyone the evolution of the question. Yes, I started from the hypotheses of continuity and non-decrease of the function, but since I didn't receive any answers I shifted my attention to the more general result that had been suggested to me, after all this is also fine.

Ok, and again (as also asked before by Behnam): please explain (in your post) what exactly you do not understand in that proof.

The following proof is a more explicit version of the one already mentioned above. If anything remains unclear, I’ll be happy to provide clarification.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary function, and $\Sigma$ the set of $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f’(x)$ exists and equals $0$. Then $f(\Sigma)$ has measure $0$.

Proof
Since $$m(f(\Sigma))\leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} m(f(\Sigma \cap [n, n+1]))$$ (by $\sigma$-subadditivity), we can assume the domain of $f$ to be the interval $[0,1]$, i.e. if all of the measures of the series are $0$, then so must the measure of $f(\Sigma)$. Fix  $\varepsilon >0$, and let $x\in \Sigma$. Since
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=0,
$$
there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\left| \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \right|<\frac\varepsilon5,$$
for all $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$. Now define $I_x=(x-\delta/5,x+\delta/5)$. We can choose $\delta$ small enough so that $I_x\subset [0,1]$. Now let $z\in 5I_x$ (if and only if $|z-x|<\delta$). Then $$|f(z)-f(x)|<|z-x|\frac{\varepsilon}5< \frac{\delta\varepsilon}5 .$$
So $$f(z)\in (f(x)-\delta\varepsilon/5,f(x)+ \delta \varepsilon/5)=:J_x,$$ which implies $f(5I_x)\subset J_x$, and  importantly $m(J_x)=2\delta\varepsilon/5 = \varepsilon m(I_x)$.
Now by Vitali’s covering lemma there exists a countable collection $\{x_i\}$ such that the intervals $I_{x_i}$ are disjoint and the intervals $5I_{x_i}$ cover $\Sigma$. Since $I_{x_i}$ are disjoint and $I_{x_i}\subset [0,1]$, we have $\sum_i m(I_{x_i})\leq m([0,1])= 1$. Since $\Sigma$ is covered by $\{5I_{x_i}\}$, and $f(5I_{x_i})\subset J_{x_i}$ for each $i$, we have that $f(\Sigma)$ is covered by $\{J_{x_i}\}$. Finally
$$
m(f(\Sigma))\leq m\left(\bigcup_i J_{x_i}\right)\\ \leq \sum_im(J_{x_i})=\varepsilon  \sum_im(I_{x_i})\leq \varepsilon, $$
but $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, so $m(f(\Sigma))=0$.

Edit: clarification of the usage of Vitali’s covering lemma.
Although Vitali’s (infinite) covering lemma holds for all separable metric spaces, I’ll formulate it in the case of $\mathbb{R}$.

If $\mathbf{F}$ is a family of intervals where
$$
\sup \{\ell(I)\mid I\in \mathbf{F}\}<\infty,
$$
i.e. the lengths of the intervals are bounded ($\ell(I)$ denotes the length of $I$). Then there exists a countable subfamily of intervals $\mathbf{G}\subseteq \mathbf{F}$ such that the elements of $\mathbf{G}$ are pairwise disjoint, and
$$
\bigcup_{I\in \mathbf{F}}I\subseteq \bigcup_{I\in \mathbf{G}} 5I, 
$$
Where $5I$ denotes the interval of length $5\ell(I)$ with the same midpoint as $I$.

Why does the countable collection $\{x_i\}$ mentioned in the proof exist?
The construction of $I_x$ and $J_x$ is of course for each $x\in \Sigma$. Thus, the family of intervals (with bounded lengths, $\ell(I_x)\leq 1$) $\mathbf{F}=\{I_{x}\mid x\in \Sigma\}$ has a countable subfamily, $\mathbf{G}$, of intervals as described in the lemma. The midpoints of those intervals are, by definition, the $\{x_i\}$.
Why do the intervals $5I_{x_i}$ cover $\Sigma$?
Since $$\Sigma=\{x\in \Sigma\}\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in \Sigma} I_x\subseteq \bigcup_{i} 5I_{x_i},$$
by the construction of the $\{x_i\}$ in Vitali’s covering lemma.

@NatMath. What is it you don’t understand about the proof?

@JanThanks, The application of Vitali's lemma is not clear to me. ${x_i}$ is a Vitali covering of $\Sigma$? Why the intervals $5I_{x_i}$ cover $\Sigma$?

I don't know this version of Vitali's Lemma. Shouldn't we find closed intervals such that $E$ minus the union of these intervals is less than epsilon?

$z\in 5I_x$ means that $z$ is in an interval five times longer than $I_x$?

Correct, with the same midpoint as $I_x$. I’m currently editing the post for clarification.

I stated the version of Vitali’s covering lemma that we used here in the edit.

@JanThanks, so $I_x$ is a vital cover of $E$?

@JanI'm sorry but I can't understand how Vitali's covering lemma applies.

No problem! I think the confusion stems from the fact that this we’re using the (weaker) covering lemma instead of Vitali’s covering theorem. And no, ${I_x}$ isn’t a Vitali covering of $E=\Sigma$, since the lemma doesn’t require that.

To be precise, I am referring to Vitali's cover theorem on page 262 of Hewitt-Stromberg Real and Abstract Analysis.

@JanI don't understand what result you are referring to. I am sorry.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
